# Need to produce JSON in specific format

Tags: json, jquery

I have such JSON array in file

```
var jsonfromfile = [
[Date.UTC(2004, 1, 3), 19.3],
[Date.UTC(2004, 1, 10), 12.7],
[Date.UTC(2004, 1, 17), 3.6],
[Date.UTC(2004, 1, 24), 19.1],
[Date.UTC(2004, 1, 31), 12.1],
[Date.UTC(2004, 2, 7), 11.3],
[Date.UTC(2004, 2, 28), 9.3],
[Date.UTC(2004, 3, 6), 14.3],
[Date.UTC(2004, 3, 13), 5.8],
[Date.UTC(2004, 3, 20), 8.6],
[Date.UTC(2004, 3, 27), 19.9],
[Date.UTC(2004, 4, 3), 14.2],
[Date.UTC(2004, 4, 10), 12.8],
[Date.UTC(2004, 4, 17), 10.6],
[Date.UTC(2004, 4, 24), 8.4],
[Date.UTC(2004, 5, 1), 19.8],
[Date.UTC(2004, 5, 8), 13.8]
];
```

Which i was using as dummy data making first steps with this charts http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock.

Now i want to use dynamic data with that charts, so i have controller which returning Key-Value data

```
public virtual JsonResult GetData(int type)
        {            
            Dictionary<string, decimal> data = getData(type);           

            return Json(data.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and i calling that controller with jquery ajax.

```
    var jsonFirstTry  = {        
                data: []
            };

            $.ajax({

                url: actionUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: { type: type },

                success: function (items) {
                    var jsonSecondTry = "[";
                    $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {

                        jsonFirstTry.data.push(item.Key, item.Value);

                        jsonSecondTry += "[" + item.Key + "," + item.Value + "],";

                    })

                    jsonSecondTry = jsonSecondTry.substring(0, jsonSecondTry.length-1);

                    jsonSecondTry += "];";

                    //...
              }
});
```

I was trying reproduce the data like in js file (`jsonfromfile`) `jsonFirstTry`  and `jsonSecondTry`  but couldn't do the data exactly like in js file

Here is how the data loaded from js file looking in debug like that:
[image: Json loaded from file]

Here is how data looking from my first try
[image: FirstTry]

Here is second try data(but it is just string so it is not valid data for chart....)

[image: Second try]

So i need to generate the same jason like in first image, any thoughts how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial example ( `var jsonfromfile = [...` ) is not JSON. It is an array of arrays (in JavaScript), using JavaScript's array literal syntax.

JSON is a string representing a serialized data structure, using a subset of the JavaScript object literal syntax.  JSON cannot have method calls or method definitions.

Thus, attempting to provide, in JSON format, what you used as sample data will not work. You need to provide real JSON and manipulate it as needed (calling `Date.UTC()` on portions of it) when received.